# Account already exists for Android Emulator for VS2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, mobile, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I tried repairing my Android Emulator for VS overnight, and this morning I see it failed, with this being the first error message in the log:

```
Automatic updates could not be paused due to error: 0x80040154. Continuing...
MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (platform.api17.msi) failed: Error Message Id: 1316 ErrorMessage: The specified account already exists.
Error 0x80070643: Failed to run maintanance mode for MSI package.
MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023293 (0x80070643), Error Message=The specified account already exists.
Automatic updates could not be paused due to error: 0x80040154. Continuing...
Automatic updates could not be paused due to error: 0x80040154. Continuing...
```

The above is not a contiguous extract from the log file, only unique error messages. All of the above appear several times.

I have been trying for three days now. Just what does it take to get this emulator working in VS2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates one of two things:

1. You already have the product installed (this version or a newer version).
2. There was an error during the acquisition process. Try downloading the setup exe again and make sure your internet is connected during installation.